# When converting MP3 file to Audio, what is added on ıt and it becomes 700mb?

Tags: mp3

Bearing in mind the fact that when converting Audio file to Mp3 file a quite amaount of loss takes place then after converting Mp3 to WAV what kind of information is added on ıt and ıt becomes 80' and 700mb?
Regards

Answer (score 3):

It's just a question of encoding data:  a WAV file encodes the raw audio wave (hence its name) uncompressed with (for CD quality) a sample rate of 44,100Hz and sample size of 16 bits regardless the content (thus one minute of silence take the same space as one minute of noise: 60s × 44100s⁻¹ × 16bits = 42,336,000 bits = 5,292,000 bytes = ~5,168 kiB).  In other words the bit rate of a WAV file in CD quality is 44100s⁻¹ * 16bits = 705,6kbits/s.

MP3 (or similar lossy encodings) »throw away« parts of the sound wave an average human being won't be able to hear either (imagine a singing bird next to a motor high way) and compresses the audio to a selectable bit rate (e.g. bit rates from 128kbit/s to 320kbit/s are rather common).

But converting MP3 back to WAV does not add any information, it just encodes it uncompressed.

Answer (score 2):

A `WAV` file is uncompressed and is a much larger file size than the compressed audio files like `mp3`. There isn't anything being added to the `WAV` file, but rather it is being stored as uncompressed. It is good to note that converting a `mp3` to `wav` does not increase the audio quality of the file as it will only ever be as good as the original source.

Answer (score 1):

No information is added. An uncompressed "regular CD-quality" WAV file is simply a series of 44,100 16-bit integers per second of sound. No matter what the actual content quality may be.

Simply said: If you allot 16 bits per number, it will always take 16 bits of storage, even if the only numbers that ever occur are 5 and 6, for example.